# Completing the square in the form $(Ax + B)^2 + C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Express $$4x^2+12x+3$$ in the form $$(Ax + B)^2 + C$$

---

**What I have Tried**

I have tried expanding $(Ax + B)^2 + C$ to get $Ax^2 + 2ABx + B^2 + C$.

$4=A$ $12=2AB$ $3=B^2+C$
so therefore: $(4x+3/2)^2-6$

But however, this is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align} 4x^2 + 12x + 3 & = (4x^2 + 12x \color{blue}{+ \bf 9}) \color{blue}{\bf - 9} + 3 \\ \\ & = (2x + 3)^2 + (-6)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you have made is that you should have written $A^2 = 4$, not $A = 4$. You can then fix your solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2+12x+3 = 4x^2+12x+9-9+3 = \mathrm {(2x+3)}^{2}-6$$

Comment: I have the answer with me, your steps and reasoning would be highly appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a book with examples of this.  Hopefully you can find some online.  This is how I'd do it.  Factor out the 4 from the $x^2$ and $x$ terms:

$4(x^2 + 3x) +3$

Now you want to make what's inside the parantheses a square.  Divide the coefficient of $x$ by 2 and square the result.  That gives you $(3/2)^2=9/4$.  You have to add that to what's inside the parentheses.  But in order not to change anything, you have to substract $4*(9/4)$ from the whole thing.  That gives you

$$ 4(x^2 + 3x) +3 =  4(x^2 + 3x+9/4) +3 -4*(9/4)=4(x+3/2)^2+3-9=4(x+3/2)^2-6.$$

For some reason whoever asked the question wanted an answer in the form $(Ax+B)^2+C$, which seems kind of unusual.  For example, is you were going to graph $y=4x^2+12x+3$, you'd probably want to write it in the form $y=4(x+3/2)^2-6$, like I did above.  But we have to do what the problem asks for.  Since $4=2^2$,

$$4(x+3/2)^2-6= 2^2(x+3/2)^2-6=[2(x+3/2)]^2-6=(2x+3)^2-6.$$

NOTE: this answer may seem excessively long.  I did it this way because it is much more common for people to ask for the form $a(x+b)^2+c$, and that is the way I am used to doing it.  The form $a(x+b)^2+c$ is probably more useful, for example, if you want to graph a quadratic function.